# Can't create/write to file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/C:/temp/load_csv.csv' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, csv

hie i m using Lampp with Mysql inbuilt version 5.6.16 and toad for mysql
 i want load data to csv file located in c/temp directory
file is ok with .csv extension

table which have data is `employee56`

```
( `emp_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_salary` double DEFAULT NULL
)
```

and my try is

```
SELECT emp_id,emp_salary from employee56
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/temp/load_csv.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I'm getting this error:

> Can't create/write to file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/C:/temp/load_csv.csv' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Please help me to solve this directory location issue, thanks.

Comment: Do you know that the `L` in `LAMP` stands for `Linux`?  You are providing a Windows path to a Linux machine.  Where on your MySQL Linux box do you want to write out the file `load_csv.csv` ?

Comment: sorry sir im using this http://192.168.1.248/xampp/

Comment: No.  What path, relative to root, do you want to write your CSV file?

Comment: sir i m using linux server  and my sql directory path is \\192.168.1.248\lampp\var\mysql  .in mysql directory there are all database folder.all machins are connected to server 192.168.1.248 by network and i want to write result to my machins c/temp/load_csv.csv

Comment: i thing i want to give path of server not of local machin is it write?

Comment: Do you realize that the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` command is going to run on your _server_ and _not_ your local machine (despite that you might execute it locally)?

Comment: yes sir .but cant i write to local machin ? if No what path i need to give i really dont where i can keep csv file plz help

Comment: You should write the file on your server, and then copy it over.

Comment: i given path \\192.168.1.248\databackup\Sandeep\Seed\ritesh\load_csv.csv   first time query run  after got error File '\192.168.1.248databackupSandeepSeediteshload_csv.csv' already exists but this folder is empty

Comment: thing file created of 1 kb but it dont have data in it

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing directory structures (paths) from Windows ( disk_drive:\folder\archive.csv) in Linux ( /folder/subfolder/archive.csv)

You need to define the correct path (in Linux format) where do you want your archive to be written. If you say your path is c/temp, you need to define the absolute route from root so the query can write it in the correct path (is it `/home/c/temp`? or is it `/c/temp`?).

You can alternatively put no path and your file will be written on `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/` and then you can move it from there to the final destination.

```
SELECT emp_id,emp_salary from employee56
INTO OUTFILE 'load_csv.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```